# jQuery slider's slide event not working correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i'm using jQuery slider, in its **slide** event i wrote some codes to executes.

it only runs while i scroll the slider slowly, when the slider scrolled fastly using mouse, the codes inside **slide** event will not executes..

here is my code:

```
$( "#master" ).slider({
    value: 0,
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    step:1,
    animate: false,
    slide: function( event, ui ) { 
        /*the below will not execute when slider scrolled faster */
        $( "#ratvalue" ).val( ui.value+"%" );
        var ratval=ui.value;
        console.log(ratval);
        progNew("#master", ratval, 100);
      }
 });
```

Comment: Is there more going on here? This http://jsfiddle.net/D4q3T/1/ simple example is working fine. What is `progNew` doing?

Comment: Try calling `progNew` in `stop` event of the slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
$( "#master" ).slider({
    value: 0,
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    step:1,
    animate: false,
    stop: function( event, ui ) { 
        /*the below will work */
        $( "#ratvalue" ).val( ui.value+"%" );
        var ratval=ui.value;
        console.log(ratval);
        progNew("#master", ratval, 100);
      }
 });
```